# Julialang package REQUIRE specify remote public Git repository

Tags: dependencies, julia, dependency-management, packaging

Suppose there is a package with the following `REQUIRE` file:

```
julia 0.4
PackageFromGithub
```

AFAIU from the julia package docs [Making Your Package Available](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#making-your-package-available) one could not specify that `PackageFromGithub` should be also cloned from Github. Either one have to clone it manually or make the `PackageFromGithub` available via registering it in `METADATA`.

Is there a way to specify something like:

```
PackageFromGithub https://github.com/user-x/PackageFromGithub
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Originally I was looking for way to make my build passing on Travis. This is possible to do by adding something like this into the build script `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
  - if [[ -a .git/shallow ]]; then git fetch --unshallow; fi
  - julia -e 'Pkg.clone("https://github.com/user-x/PackageFromGithub.jl.git"); Pkg.clone(pwd()); Pkg.build("YOUR_PACKAGE"); Pkg.test("YOUR_PACKAGE"; coverage=true)'
```

In case somebody could be interested.